# Sequelize inside express route - include where model matches search terms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, join, sequelize.js

I have an inventory app that needs the capability to search through a large SQL dataset on demand (65k records). Today I ran across an issue when using the include parameter. Here's what it looks like:

```
//Get all records for passed search term
router.get('/getSearchData', function(req,res,next){

        models.assets.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'Owner', 'Barcode', 'SerialNum', 'Model', 'Last_Seen_Date', 'OrderNum',
                'Item_Status', 'Equipment_Type', 'Comments', 'AssignedLevel', 'Acquired_Date',
                'Issued_Date', 'Warranty_Exp_Date', 'Surplus_Date'
            ],
            where: { 
                [Op.or]: [
                    { Owner:             { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Barcode:           { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { SerialNum:         { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Model:             { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Last_Seen_Date:    { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { OrderNum:          { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Item_Status:       { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Equipment_Type:    { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Comments:          { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { AssignedLevel:     { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Acquired_Date:     { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Issued_Date:       { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Warranty_Exp_Date: { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                    { Surplus_Date:      { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} }
                ]
            },
            include: [
                { model: models.contacts, as: 'contacts',
                  where: {
                    [Op.or]: [
                        { Alias:         { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
                        { Last_Name:     { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} }
                    ]
                  }
                }
            ],
            order: [ [ 'Barcode', 'desc' ] ]

    }).then( response => { res.send(response);
    }).catch(error => { return next(error)});
});
```

Our inventory app is set up to show data about a specific asset, and then tie that to a contacts table that contains information about the owner of the asset. What I am trying to do here is return any results that match the users search term, across both tables.

I have the associations setup correctly, as I am using a very similar route to populate the unfiltered table.

Am I overthinking this? Or did I miss something simple? Any input would be appreciated :)

Comment: It just occurred to me that I could just create a view in SQL that takes care of all of this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer!

Sequelize was formatting my query in a strange way, adding an AND statement and appending my query string inside of the join on this query, instead of in the WHERE clause.

The solution to this was to use a [Top level where with eagerly loaded models.](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models) Applying the solution from the linked documentation, my route now looks like this:

```
router.get('/getSearchData', function(req,res,next){
 models.assets.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'Owner', 'Barcode', 'SerialNum', 'Model', 'Last_Seen_Date', 'OrderNum',
    'Item_Status', 'Equipment_Type', 'Comments', 'AssignedLevel', 'Acquired_Date',
    'Issued_Date', 'Warranty_Exp_Date', 'Surplus_Date'
  ],
  where: { 
    [Op.or]: [

        // Assets columns
        { Owner:             { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
        { Barcode:           { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
        { SerialNum:         { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
        //Other Columns......

        // Contacts columns
        { '$contacts.Alias$':     { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
        { '$contacts.Last_Name$': { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },

        // Models Columns
        { '$models.Manufacturer$': { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} },
        { '$models.Device_Type$':  { [Op.like]: '%'+req.query.string+'%'} }
    ]
  },
  include: [
    { model: models.contacts, as: 'contacts' },
    { model: models.models,   as: 'models'   }
  ],
  order: [ [ 'Barcode', 'desc' ] ]
 }).then( response => { res.send(response)
 }).catch(error => { return next(error)});
});
```

Everything works correctly with this setup, hooray!